# Regex to Select All Math Operator not Hyphen

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to implement a regex which splits the string on all math operators but no hyphen in the string:

```
dummy_string= "I Dont_Know The-Meaning_2018-You Know_Meaning_2017+You Know_Meaning_2017"

string_list = re.split("[0-9][+/*\-][A-Za-z]", dummy_string)

print(string_list)

>>['I Dont_Know The-Meaning_201', 'ou Know_Meaning_201', 'ou Know_Meaning_2017']
```

Expected Output:

```
>>['I Dont_Know The-Meaning_2018', 'You Know_Meaning_201', 'You Know_Meaning_2017']
```

I am using regex (re) package for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `(?<=[0-9])` and `(?=[A-Za-z])` lookarounds instead of consuming patterns:

```
import re
dummy_string= "I Dont_Know The-Meaning_2018-You Know_Meaning_2017+You Know_Meaning_2017"
string_list = re.split("(?<=[0-9])[+/*-](?=[A-Za-z])", dummy_string)
print(string_list)
# => ['I Dont_Know The-Meaning_2018', 'You Know_Meaning_2017', 'You Know_Meaning_2017']
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/ALW92883)

When you use `[0-9][+/*\-][A-Za-z]` to split a string, the digit before a non-word delimiter and a letter after it are *consumed*, i.e. added to the match value, and `re.split` removes this text from the resulting output. When using lookarounds, the matched texts remain "unconsumed", they are not added to the match value and thus remain in the `re.split` output.

Note that you do not have to escape `-` when it is at the end of the character class, `[+/*-]` = `[+/*\-]`. If you plan to add more chars into the class, you  may keep `-` escaped to avoid further issues.